# HTML 5 Canvas property triggered by a track progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a newbie at web coding so this may seem like a silly question but there's no harm in asking...
Is there any way i can get the progress bar of an audio track to trigger a canvas animation?? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What is the progress bar doing when the trigger happens? Changing? Getting clicked on? Getting moused over? Explain the functionality more.

Comment: its an audio stream so the user clicks to play the track - thats when i want the animation to occur, and stop when the track stops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of events that you can attach bindings to:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#mediaevents

You are probably looking for the 'play' event, so you would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('aud').play = function () {
    getElementById('can').animate();
}
```

And the 'ended' event

```
document.getElementById('aud').ended = function () {
    getElementById('can').stopAnimate();
}
```